# how to restore xp after installing windows 8

Tags: windows-xp

I have installed Windows 8 on a PC running windows xp. I was trying to get a dual boot and used advanced options in the setup, but ended up with xp on a drive and win 8 in another.

Now, the PC starts on Win 8 without the option to start win xp.

I can see win xp on the other drive, so, how to get the PC to allow dual boot without losing all my old files in xp or at least reverse back to xp for now?

Checking on MSCONFIG, Win 8 changed drive D to C, and Windows XP appears as follows:

Windows 8 (D:\Windows), where Windows in D is XP with all files and users intact.

Regards,

MD

Answer (score 0):

All I can say first is: good luck. Okay, I say that jokingly because I just dealt with this for the past week myself.

**NOTE: Before you do any of this have *complete* backups of everything, aka entire disk images. Playing with these things, such as Windows Repair/Recovery options are likely to fry your bootloader and render your system unbootable.**

You can download [easyBCD from NeoSmart](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), and add a new boot entry to the BCD menu to windows 8. This will give you an option to boot Windows XP.

But, since you've moved partitions around you will likely end up in a situation where one or more windows installs won't boot. For this you'll want to have the Windows Install/Recovery disks handy.

If Windows 8 won't boot, there is an option to *autorepair* from the Windows 8 install media (it's under *troubleshoot*).

If Windows XP won't boot, you can try the Windows XP install disc, press R for recovery mode, from the command line tools try:

```
fixboot
```

Then reboot. I would skip the command `fixmbr` here if you are using the Win8 bootloader, as this will wipe the disks mbr and replace it with Windows XP's.

In my case, Windows XP would start to boot, but never display the log in screen simply because I had moved it to a new partition. My solution was to simply reinstall Windows XP (to this same, new partition). However, even with this solution, it still required several repair console visits before everything was configured/booted properly.